# Why do I need META-INF/maven dir in my jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

Does maven use this dir in some way, or I can safely remove it from jar? Who else is using the information in maven dir?

Answer (score 0):

You can "safely" remove it in that it is not used at runtime.

Personally I use it for extracting metadata from a jar and I would not be surprised other tools do as well but that has nothing to do with actually running the code.

Disclaimer: I do have a custom classloader that uses this information to dynamically load dependencies